# AssertionError when using a TaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, junit4

I am writing a program that executes many Threads at the same time (in parallel) , I am using a TaskExecutor .

```
@Autowired TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;
@Test
public  void testSpringTaskExecutor() 
                         throws InterruptedException  {
    assertNotNull(threadPoolTaskExecutor);
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        Runnable myThread = 
                        new Workflow(new AtomicInteger(k));
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(myThread);
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
    logger.info("Finished all threads");
}
```

When I tested my code an AssertionError exeption was raised . I'm using the Spring Framework to manage the execution .

here is the log screen  :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:92)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:526)
```

Any one have any ideas please :) Thank you

Comment: What did you expect? Where did you initialize the thread pool task executor?

Comment: the class that implements the testSpringTaskExecutor method inherit from another class that get the context from a configuration file @ContextConfiguration(classes={JavaConfigurator.class})
and i'm using the annotation @Autowired ApplicationContext sprinCtx;

Comment: This is all fine and good, but obviously this did not initialize it, did it?

Comment: no , i cant take the context from the parent Class , that is the problem ,@Autowired does that but it is not working

Comment: It looks like threadPoolTaskExecutor is package scoped.  Is your parent class in the same package?  Does it work better if you have public getter/setter methods for it?

Comment: do you use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation?

Comment: @Andrew Yes i used  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation

Pace : all my classes are in the same package

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution , I have to initialize the threadPoolTaskExecutor so when we use assertNotNull(threadPoolTaskExecutor);  the object will be initialized and we can execute our threads .

Here is the initialize method :

```
 public void initialize() {
                     logger.info("Creating ThreadPoolExecutor");
                     BlockingQueue   queue = createQueue(this.queueCapacity);
                    executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor  (
                             this.corePoolSize, this.maxPoolSize, this.keepAliveSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                             queue, this.threadFactory, this.rejectedExecutionHandler);
                 }
```

and here is the executorService definition :

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor executorService;
```

Thank You Andrew and Pace and Ingo for your help :)